# Simple way to insert foreign key automatically into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table `program(p_id(pk)AI, program_name` and another table `graduate_survey(id(pk)AI,total_PO1,total_PO2,session,p_id(fk)`. In the program table values are already inserted as

```
p_id Program_name
    1    B.tech CSE
    2    B.tech IT.
```

..so on. I select from a drop down list B.tech CSE and then redirect to the survey form. I enter the total_PO1, total_PO2 there and submit it.Now i want to insert in the graduate_survey table where in the fk field the p_id of B.tech CSE should automatically enter so that i can know the survey is done for which program..Is there any query in MySQL to do that? The insert operation should be done in php code.Please suggest any query.

Comment: If you want to do this in PHP instead of using MySQL triggers, then this isn't really going to be "automatic".

Comment: so how to do this using MySQL triggers?

Comment: May take a bit of reading http://tutsheap.com/web/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/

Comment: MySQL triggers cannot be executed using php code?

Comment: @Flosculus this is not sg I would use triggers for.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be incorrect. When you generate your dropdown menu in HTML, then the display value (the value that the user actually sees and selects) should be the program name, but the underlying value should be the id of the same record.

When you send the data to the server, then you should send the underlying id value, not the display value. Using HTML's standard dropdown menu, you would create sg like this as an output:

```
<select name="programs">
    <option value="1">B.tech CSE</option>
    <option value="2">B.tech IT</option>
</select>
```

If this control is submitted via a form, then the browser will send the `value` of the selected option automatically. If you use ajax, then your code has to retrieve the selected value of the select element. In the php code you just insert the underlying value into the graduate survey table.

Comment: I did it in the form but how to pass that id value? is there any query?

Comment: you said absolutely right..i have lost that logic how to send the underlying id value?

Comment: okk i got it.. Thank you..After that can i insert the foreign key automatically?

Comment: This way you have the `p_id` value for the selected program and can just simply insert it into the database.

Comment: $sql="SELECT * from programs WHERE Program_name='$program'";.......if i give option value in the select element is this query is correct or i have to take the $p_id? or $sql="SELECT * from programs WHERE p_id='$p_id'";  which is correct?

Comment: This is not working...if you can give your code please share so that i can understand.

Comment: Why do you want to select anything from the programs table if you want to populate the surveys table?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat so that i can tell you briefly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not do help in chats.